# Text calendar date to Julian date in excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-2011

I have a column of yymmdd dates formatted as text (ex: 970623) I'm trying to convert into Julian date in Excel 2011. I've tried converting to excel-formatted date, but it throws me back into the 1950s with all of my dates. I also found a suggestion online about using error check in excel. Any ideas for formulas to tease this column into Julian date?

Thanks very much,

Mo

Comment: People seem to define the term "Julian Date" in many different ways - how are you defining it - can you give an example? If you have the value 970623 - that is supposed to be 23rd June 1997 I presume - what do you want to convert to in that case? How is a date like 1st Jan 2000 shown in your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to use the DATE function as follows:

```
B1=DATE(LEFT(A1,2), MID(A1,3,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

This will turn your text into an Excel date.

Then, assume you're looking for a 2-digit year and 3-digit Day-Of-Year, just calculate the difference between that day and the 1st day of the year.  So:

```
C1=RIGHT(YEAR(B1),2)&B1-DATE(YEAR(B1),1,1)
```

That should give you the Julian date.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to decide at which point you decide if it's 20xx or 19xx for the year, and using that, create the value

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(VALUE(IF(VALUE(LEFT(A2,2))<50,"20","19")&A2),"0000-00-00"))
```

or if they are all 19xx dates,

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(VALUE("19"&A2),"0000-00-00"))
```

This formula will add a 19 or 20 to the beginning, depending on the year, then convert that to a number, then convert that to a formatted number that excel can understand is a date (yyyy-mm-dd)
Format the result as you would any other date.

from [CPearson's](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/jdates.htm) very useful website,

The formula below will convert a standard Excel date in A1 to a Julian Date.

```
=RIGHT(YEAR(A1),2)&TEXT(A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0),"000")
```

Comment: Thank you! However this formula actually changed my dates into calendar dates, not julian dates. I am using 1900 as the base date, not 2000.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was incorrect and I am over the 5 minute edit time - this formula changed my example date to 35604?

Comment: As per my comment on your question - for the example 970623, what result do you want?

Comment: @MoCorrell, see my edit to convert the regular excel date (yes, 35604 is an excel date, 6/23/1997)